# Как добавить русские символы в тег UserComment в exif файла

Tags: android, exif

Как добавить русские символы в тег `UserComment` в `exif` файла.
Я для этого использовал такой код:

```
exifInterface.setAttribute("UserComment", charSequence.toString());
exifInterface.saveAttributes();
```

или

```
exifInterface.setAttribute("UserComment", new String(charSequence.toString().getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
exifInterface.saveAttributes();
```

Но вместо символов сохраняется символ `?`.

Comment: А вы чем смотрите exif?

Comment: Стандартными средствами из пакета android.media.ExifInterface;

Comment: Есть сторонние приложения, которые тоже редактируют атрибуты файла, в них кириллица добавляется правильно.

Comment: Попробуйте кодировку `UCS-2`

Comment: Попробовал. Результат тот же. Я разные на самом деле кодировки пробовал, и UTF-8, и UTF-16, и ASCII.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать ExifInterface из либ суппорта: `com.android.support.exifinterface` - судя по исходникам, не все теги поддерживаются в некоторых версиях андроида, а в суппорте вроде все теги есть -[см. сюда](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/43dbd2ac615a6829f24b3504a9c311e79db78df4/exifinterface/src/android/support/media/ExifInterface.java)

Comment: Все равно не получается :(